# How to scale mysql tables for growth

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm working on site that will replace an older site with a lot of traffic, and I will also have a lot of data in the DB, so my question to you guys is what is the best way to design mysql tables for growth?

I was thinking to split let's say a table with 5 000 000 rows in 5 tables,with 1 000 000 rows/table and create a relationship between the tables, but I guess this isn't a good option since I will spend a lot of resources and time to figure out in what table my data is.

Or can you guys give me some tips mabe some useful articles?

Comment: You want partitioning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: Or you might just want to use the MySQL cluster. Probably it's time to spend some money. Comes with full support, you can contact pre-sales support as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're absolutely right on the relationships. This technique is called [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) where you define separate tables because these individual tables are affected with time and independent of other tables.

So if you have a hotel database that keeps a track of rooms and guests, then you know normalization is necessary because rooms and guests are independent of each other.

But you will have foreign keys/surrogate keys in each table (for instance, room_id) that could relate the particular guest entering for that particular room.

Normalization, in your case, could help you optimize that 5000 rows of yours as it would not be optimal for a loop to go over 5000 elements and retrieve an entire data.

Here is a strong [example](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~gwiggins/syllabi/csc415/normalization-examples.html) for why normalization is essential in database management.

Comment: So when I have to query the DB what I do? INNER JOIN? eg: INNER JOIN table1,table2,table3,table4,table5....

Comment: I guess doing an inner join isn't so smart...since it will take the same time as with just one big table...but probabily there is a method , some key reference to know in what table your data that you are looking for is.

Comment: You can do a simple JOIN. For instance, `$query="SELECT room_number, room_guest FROM room JOIN guest ON  room.room_id=guest.room_id WHERE booking_data='$date' ";` will get the room booking details for a particular date by joining `room` and `guests` table. Make sure room_id is a foreign key in your guest table.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning as mentioned in a comment is one way to go, but the first path to check out is even determining if you can break down the tables with the large amounts of data into workable chunks based on some internal data.

For instance, lets say you have a huge table of contacts.  You can essentially break down the data into contacts that start from a-d, e-j, etc.  Then when you go to add records you just make sure you add the records to the correct table (I'd suggest checking out stored procedures for handling this, so that logic is regulated in the database).  You'd also probably set up stored procedures to also get data from the same tables.  By doing this however, you have to realize that using auto-incrementing IDs won't work correctly as you won't be able to maintain unique IDs across all of the tables without doing some work yourself.

These of course are the simple solutions.  There are tons of solutions for large data sets which also includes looking at other storage solutions, clustering, partitioning, etc.  Doing some of these things manually yourself can give you a little bit of an understanding on some of the possibly "manual solutions".